Bounded differentiation operator on compact intervals with $L^2$ norm
It is known that the differentiation operator $D$ is not bounded on $C^1([0,1])$ with $L^2$ norm (counterexample: $f(x)=x^n$). Now I am wondering whether there is an infinitely dimensional subspace such that $D$ is indeed bounded on it? For example,
$$
X=\{f\in C^{\infty}([0,1])\vert\sup_{n\ge0}\Vert f^{(n)}\Vert_{\infty}<\infty\}
$$
(I do not know whether it is true and cannot give a proof)? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Not sure if it helps but the derivative is bounded wrt the norm $|f|\infty + |f'|\infty$

@EvangelopoulosFoivos that’s only if you consider $D$ as a map $C^1([0,1])\to C([0,1])$. But it seems like OP wants a single normed space $X$ and to consider $D:X\to X$; so in this case OP’s suggestion is indeed the right way to go.

Here is a very partial result which could be helpful:

Theorem.
Given a subspace $X\subset C^1([0,1])$, consider the following statements.

the 1-dimensional Sobolev-type inequality holds on $X$, i.e there exists a $B>0$ such that for all $f\in X$
\begin{align}
\|f\|_{C^0([0,1])}\leq B\|f’\|_{L^2([0,1])},
\end{align}
i.e $D=\frac{d}{dx}:(X,\|\cdot\|_{C^0([0,1])})\to L^2([0,1])$ is lower-bounded.

$D=\frac{d}{dx}:(X,\|\cdot\|_{L^2([0,1])})\to L^2([0,1])$ is bounded.

$X$ is finite-dimensional and does not contain the constant function $1$.


Then, statements $(1)$ and $(2)$ together are equivalent to $(3)$.

To prove that $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply $(3)$, observe that our two assumptions imply that the inclusion map $(X,\|\cdot\|_{L^2([0,1])})\hookrightarrow C^0([0,1])$ is bounded (with operator norm at most $B\|D\|$). Thus, by a classic result, $X$ must be finite-dimensional. Next, our assumption (1) implies that $1\notin X$ (otherwise, we’d get $1\leq B\cdot 0=0$). This proves (3).
Conversely, (3) immediately implies (2) (recall that any linear map between normed spaces with finite-dimensional domain is bounded). To prove (1), observe first that $D:X\to L^2([0,1])$ is injective; this is because $D(f)=0$ implies $f$ is a constant $c$. If $c\neq 0$, then $X$ being a subspace implies $1=\frac{f}{c}\in X$, contrary to our assumption (3). Thus, $f=c=0$, proving injectivity. Thus, $D$ has an inverse $D^{-1}:(\text{image}(D),\,\|\cdot\|_{L^2([0,1])})\to (X,\|\cdot\|_{C^0([0,1])})$. Since $X$ is finite-dimensional, so is the image of $D$, hence $D^{-1}$ is bounded (same reason as above), and this is equivalent to $D$ being lower-bounded. Thus, (1) holds.
But it seems like this just trades one difficulty for another, since Im not quite sure how to characterize all $X$ for which the Sobolev-type inequality holds.

My point is to find a subset of $C^{\infty}([0,1])$ such that $D$ is bounded on it. The example you gave is not in the subspace $X$ that I mentioned in my question.

Sorry, but I think you got me wrong. I am wondering whether $D$ is bounded on $X$ with the $L^2$ norm.

@graham oh. well as long as $X\subset C^{\infty}([0,1])$ contains all monomials (which is the case with your example), then $D:(X,|\cdot|{L^2([0,1])})\to (X,|\cdot|{L^2([0,1])})$ cannot be bounded; just consider $f_n(x)=x^n$. There still remains the question of whether there exists any other infinite-dimensional subspace $X\subset C^{\infty}([0,1])$ for which $D:(X,|\cdot|{L^2([0,1])})\to (X,|\cdot|{L^2([0,1])})$ might be bounded… this I’m not sure.
